# Parse Oracle output to a specific format

Tags: oracle, parsing

I have cust_nm column in a database.  The column cust_nm is formatted with  last name then first name are separated by a comma followed by a space than the middle initial.

TUNGESVIK, MARK M

I want to run a Oracle query to output this format.

Comment: What about the other 50% of names in the world?

Comment: Your username is "oracledba" and you have to ask this? ...

Comment: It would help if your question including what it is that you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If all your names are really in that exact format, you can do something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 'TUNGESVIK, MARK M' cust_nm from dual
  3  )
  4  select substr( cust_nm, 1, instr(cust_nm, ', ')-1 ) last_name,
  5         substr( cust_nm, instr(cust_nm, ', ')+2, instr(cust_nm, ' ', -1) - instr(cust_nm, ', ')-2) first_name,
  6         substr( cust_nm, instr(cust_nm, ' ', -1)+1, length(cust_nm) ) middle_initial
  7*   from x
SQL> /

LAST_NAME FIRS M
--------- ---- -
TUNGESVIK MARK M
```

When you start including people that don't have a middle initial (or that have multiple middle initials), people with multiple spaces in their last or first name, the probability that at least some names aren't in this format but some other format, things get a lot more challenging.  There are software products whose only purpose is to take incoming name data, parse it, scrub it, and standardize it.  Writing your own code to try to handle every corner case is likely to take way more time than you're expecting.

Comment: THATS THE PROBLEM ALL HE NAMES ARE NOT IN  THAT FORMAT

Comment: KESSELHEIM, HOWARD /  WILLIAMSON, STEPHEN KENT / COSTA, DANIEL ////////////////////////    SOME HAVE LAST,FIRST MIDDLE  /    SOME ONLY HAVE LAST,FIRST      /WITH THAT QUERY YOU PROVIDED MIDDLE INITIAL ONE IS PICKING UP FIRST NAME TOO...ALSO THE FIRST NAME ONLY PICKS UP FOR SOME ROWS AND DOESN'T PICK UP FOR OTHER ROWS

Comment: @oracledba - If there are different formats, your question needs to include sample data that covers every format you want to handle.  Depending on the formats, you may also need to specify in your question the order of priority for interpreting names using different formats.  As I said, though, parsing name data quickly becomes a nearly intractable problem where you need to bring in a data cleansing tool to do it correctly.  Note that when you edit your question to include this information, you'll want to make sure that your CAPS LOCK key isn't on.